# What does `a += b += c` mean?

Tags: syntax

I saw the following code: `a += b += c` - please, does anyone know what does it mean?

```
a = a + b
b = b + c
```

or:

```
b = b + c
a = a + b
```

Comment: 1) in what language? 2) did you try it?

Comment: It would be your second block.

Comment: It means some previous developer was a sociopath.

Comment: Agree with @invertedSpear. If this code is in your codebase, you should figure out what it's effect is and then replace with clearer code. This code snippet is objectively terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can only be evaluated as:

```
a += (b += c)
```

If it would be evaluated as this:

```
(a += b) += c
```

then it would evaluate `a += b` to a numeric value, and then try to change the numeric value, not a variable, which is not possible.

Comment: Ahem. It's the necessary condition, but it's not the only one; if `+=` returns an lvalue (and it's often so; `(a += b) += c` is correct syntax in C++ ([proof](http://codepad.org/588YbDde)), for example), it's associativity what matters.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on associativity of `+=` operator. Usually it's right to left, so it's the second answer: `a+=b` is evaluated after `b+=c`.

Comment: How would that work if the associativity is not right to left? If the expression `a += b` returns for example `5`, what would `5 += c` mean?

Comment: @Guffa Nice catch; LTR here is possible only if result of shortcut assignment is lvalue itself. So it's not only the question of associativity. )

Answer (score 0):

In most high-level languages, expressions like this are evaluated left to right because `+=` is right-to-left associative. In this case, the value of `c` is added to the value of `b`, then the value of `b` (after addition by `c`) is added to `a`.

This is equivalent to your second block.